# Accepts Nested attributes using mongoid for has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am a bit new to using Mongoid, but have significant experience with ActiveRecord. I have the following models

```
def Company
  field :name

  has_one :owner, autosave: true, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end

def User
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :owner
  has_one :profile
end
```

My RegistrationController has the following method

```
def new 
  @company = Company.new
  @company.build_owner
  @company.owner.build_profile
  respond_with @company
end
```

And in my view...

```
= simple_form_for @company, url: user_registration_path do |f| 
  = f.error_notification
  .inputs
    = f.simple_fields_for @company.owner do |o| 
      = o.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true
      = o.simple_fields_for @company.owner.profile do |p| 
        = p.input :first_name, required: true
        = p.input :last_name, required: true
      = f.input :name, label: 'Company Name'
      = f.input :subdomain
      = o.input :password, required: true
      = o.input :password_confirmation, required: true
  .actions
    = f.button :submit, "Sign up"
```

Whenever I submit this form, the params are returned such that:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"6z8+evYUwZwx3iADFewsMHiPl00vT7Eq6WaD8BOnQBc=",
 "company"=>
  {"user"=>
    {"email"=>"testing@testing.com",
     "profile"=>{"first_name"=>"testing", "last_name"=>"testing"},
     "password"=>"testing",
     "password_confirmation"=>"testing"},
   "name"=>"testing",
   "subdomain"=>"testing"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"users/registrations"}
```

Firstly, I don't understand why the user attributes have the key :user, shouldn't it be :user_attributes or :owner_attributes? The examples on the mongoid website seem to suggest that. Secondly when i do company = Company.new(params[:company]) and do company.owner on that object I get a nil object. However, doing company.user returns me that correct user object. I've figured out that if in the params the key is :owner (instead of :user) the association should work fine. But that is not happening by default. Maybe it is something to do with simpleform? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I would try removing simple_form from the equation and just use the standard form_for/fields_for methods. Also, make sure your models declare accept_nested_fields_for for the associated objects. Does it work if you change Company to have a :user association instead of :owner?

Answer (score 0):

The field should be called `owner` as that is the name of the field in your model.

What happens when you call it `user` is that mongoid creates a dynamic field in the model - `company[user]`. This is the correct behavior and quite a powerful tool when used correctly.

I don't know `simple_form` but the way to do this in standard rails is to call `f.fields_for :owner`, which should give you the functionality you expect.